# `model.frame` does not see object defined within `foreach` parallel loop

Tags: r, foreach, domc

I first encountered my problem while trying to find the best pruned classification tree with `cv.tree` in `library(tree)`. I have traced the cause to `model.frame` called within `cv.tree`. Here's a MWE:

```
library(tree)
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
data(iris)

registerDoMc(1)
foreach (i=(1:1)) %dopar% {
  d <- iris
  full_tree <- tree(Species ~ ., data=d)
  model.frame(full_tree)
}

Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'd' not found"
```

Could anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: If I copy/paste this into R I don't get that error (doMC_1.3.3, foreach_1.4.2, tree_1.0-35 and R version 3.1.0)

Comment: @MrFlick I forgot to use `registerDoMc(1)` in my question. The error only pops up if we use parallel backend. The code should produce an error now. I have identical packages to yours.